# Addon domain redirects to Main Domain

Tags: networking, nginx, domain-name-system

I have a VPS from Ramnode which I am using to host my primary domain http://african-dreamtravel.de/ and I went on adding another domain (http://www.lagerregal-pruefen.de/) to the VPS today. Although, the www version of the new domain redirects to main domain instead of loading it's own site. Non www version loads fine. Both the domains have thier A record set to the VPS IP. I am running Nginx on the VPS and have configured Virtual Host. I am at my wit's end and not able to resolve this issue. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: What is your nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the primary domain is the default and you forgot to add the www domain to the [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) directive in the server block of the new domain.

```
server_name lagerregal-pruefen.de www.lagerregal-pruefen.de;
```

would make the server block listen to the www version.
If you already have this in your config you should upload your config!